# WPF usercontrol binding to object don't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a problem with binding my usercontrol to object in mainwindow. I don't know what is wrong.

I created custom control MyUserControl which has editable textbox

**MyUsrControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlToObject.MyUsrControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="70" d:DesignWidth="200">    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">Name</Label>            
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Name="tbxName"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Next I defined DP to allow modify this textbox outside countrol

**MyUsrControl.xaml.cs**

```
namespace UserControlToObject
{
    public partial class MyUsrControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EmpNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EmpNameProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUsrControl),           
                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, EmpNamePropertyChanged));

        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(EmpNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EmpNameProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public MyUsrControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        static void EmpNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyUsrControl x = (MyUsrControl)sender;
            x.tbxName.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I defined Employee class - properties of object of this class will be displayed on user control

```
namespace UserControlToObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Employee class
    /// </summary>
    class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string m_name, m_surname;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Employee name property
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_name; }
            set
            {
                m_name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Employee surname property
        /// </summary>
        public string Surname
        {
            get { return m_surname; }
            set
            {
                m_surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }

        public Employee()
        {
            m_name = "unknown name";
            m_surname = "unknown surname";
        }

        public Employee(string name, string surname)
        {
            m_name = name;
            m_surname = surname;
        }    

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

    }
```

And finally MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Name="myApp" x:Class="UserControlToObject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlToObject"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyUsrControl x:Name="ucEmp" EmpName="{Binding Name}"></local:MyUsrControl>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=ucEmp, Path=EmpName}"></Label>

    </StackPanel>
</Window
```

>

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace UserControlToObject
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Employee anEmployee;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            anEmployee = new Employee("John", "Wayne");

            this.DataContext = anEmployee;         
        }

    }
```

}

This line don't work (error saying that I can set binding only on DependencyProperty... of DependencyObject):

```
<local:MyUsrControl x:Name="ucEmp" EmpName="{Binding Name}"></local:MyUsrControl>
```

Those settings below works, so I think that's problem with my Employee class (sth is missing ?)

```
<local:MyUsrControl x:Name="ucEmp" EmpName="John"></local:MyUsrControl> --> set EmpName ok
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=ucEmp, Path=EmpName}"></Label> --> get EmpName ok
```

I've no idea whot is wrong, so will be very greatfull for help

I did the same but binding TextBox instead of user control and was no problem. 
TextBox.Text is dependency property same as my Employee.EmpName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When registering the dependency property you need to use the name that you want to use in XAML. In your case, this is `EmpName` and not `EmpNameProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EmpNameProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register(nameof(EmpName), typeof(string), typeof(MyUsrControl), new 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.
    BindsTwoWayByDefault, EmpNamePropertyChanged));
```

Comment: One more question. Why this binding works one way. If I type some text in control anEmployee.Name don't change. But if I change anEmployee.Name in code, text is set into control. I even set TwoWay mode but no results

Comment: @czechoww: Your user control doesn't use data binding internally and you don't employ any other way to write the contents of the text box to the property. If this comment doesn't solve that problem, you should ask a new question.

Comment: You are right. I added setting EmpNameProperty on TextChange event and now it works great. Thanx again.

Comment: Why was this not marked as the answer @czechoww ? The answer came first and explains exactly what is going on with an example, coupled with the comments to explain the additional question you had!!

Answer (score 0):

"EmpNameProperty" in your property registeration should be ""EmpName"" w.

Thanks